# Bidirectional connection between a device and a webserver

Tags: microcontroller, communication

I'm a software developer, I'm in no way familiar with electronic devices but I'm working with people who are familiar with them. Our problem is: We need to design a small device able to communicate with a webserver.

We have covered the device-to-server using http requests, but how can we talk to the device from the server?

**Requirements:**

Must be wireless

Range: I believe it will be via GSM, so I understand it'll require to be within signal radius.

Size: 4cm width, 2cm height, 2cm wide aprox.

Power consumption: I couldn't say, it'll probably need to work with less than 600mAh as battery source.

Thanks in advance for any tips, guidance you can give us.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "push notification". There are a number of different platforms/ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of push notifications and I tried to search about that before posting the question. But all I found was related to the Arduino/similar hardware, which is not viable for us due the physical size...

Comment: Well, you're going to have to enumerate what sort of requirements you have.  Wired or wireless?  Range?  Size of communications?  Power and size constraints?  Timescale?

Comment: I updated with all the info I currently have.

Comment: I think the device makes a http request using chunked transfer for the content length. This keeps the request open (the device doesn't know how long the reply will be) and then the server can just keep streaming data.

Comment: There are quite a few IoT libraries out there. The Xively one comes to mind. These have an implementation of a REST interface which you might be able to draw inspiration from.

Comment: Isn't that really taxing power-wise? And as "taxing" I mean consuming more than it could using a different approach.

Comment: Power consumption is measured in watts, not Ah.  You can run a lot of stuff on 600 mAh.  If you are going to specify Ah, then you also need to specify volts and how long you want to run it for.  Which will enable calculating the power consumption in watts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most cellular modems are square rather than rectangular and may be as big as 40mm square.  One of the smaller ones that almost meets your requirements is the Sierra quad-band GSM/GPRS [AirPrime HL6528](http://www.eltech.spb.ru/files/item/HL6528.pdf) which is 22mm x 23mm x 2.5mm.  Remember in addition to that space, you will also need an [antenna](http://www.antenova-m2m.com/products/giganova-standard-antennas) which takes up quite a bit of space and a SIM card holder.

I have done a couple of different products where we needed to have a bi-directional communication channel open to a server, and be able to initiate a session from either end.  A program was written in C# (.NET) that handled the server side, which sat on a specific port and listened for incoming connections (for example, 111.222.333.444:5555).

Using the necessary AT commands for the cellular modem (the ones for setting up data connections are generally proprietary to each manufacturer), a TCP/IP connection was set up between the modem and the port on the server.  At that point, without any extra protocol (other than what we designed for ourselves), the modem could "talk" directly back and forth to the server.

***Now if the server wanted to initiate a communication*** to the cellular modem, the trick there is to get attention of the device without already having an active connection up all the time (the modem of course still needs to be powered up and registered on the network).

One could attempt to make a "call" to the phone number associated with the modem.  But frankly I didn't know how to do that from the server.  Instead, what I did was to send an SMS message from the server to the modem (there are lots of web services designed to do this), and then the device firmware would know to "call home".  There were at set of commands for the modem that allowed one to listen for incoming SMS messages; very little coding was required to handle them.  This also allows for the minimal power you can get away with and still be on the network.

To avoid SMS fees, another possibility would be to hang a GSM modem off of your server on a USB to UART cable, and dial the phone number of your device. It would then go RING ... RING. You could use this as the indication to "call home". Since the call is never answered, you shouldn't get charged for it. The phone number of your modem (which is actually stored in the SIM) should be available via an AT command.

As far as power consumption goes, that all depends on the duty cycle of your messages. The particular modem I linked to above takes a maximum of 360 mA. So the average is probably a lot less, but let's stick with the maximum as a worst case.  If each data session takes two minutes, and you send once an hour, with a 600mAh battery it would last a maximum of 600 / (360 / (60/2)) = 50 hours, which doesn't included standby current.  Let's assume that is 10% of the maximum, so now you have 45 hours.  Plus you can't actually drain a battery all the way to zero.

Comment: We considered SMS to let the device know we wanted to initiate the communication, but in our country SMS are expensive and this event will happen quite frequently, making it not viable...

But yeah, currently is our only way. We'll look into the GSM modules you linked, I really appreciate that you took the time to write this nice and detailed answer.

Comment: @Areks please see an update to my answer on another way to contact your device without using SMS.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do it is by polling http request. If you are a software developer you'd probably have already played with AJAX and polling XHR on web pages. Same concept only implemented in hardware.

If you want a persistent connection you may want to look at websockets. The specification is fairly simple so it's not too hard to implement in the hardware.

Of course, you can simply open a plain TCP connection and abandon http completely. Design your own protocol like telnet or ssh or IRC that communicates over a persistent socket. Then simply have that server program communicate with your web server (via database updates perhaps?).

Personally I'd try the first option first. It's the easiest to implement since you already have the http part working.

Comment: slebetman! I have a similar application, but for the hardware is to most expanssive keep a connection, then the output is the microcontroller receive a push when it should be triggered (connect a led for example), is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Augusto: For TCP/IP push notification requires keeping the connection open. Pull notification does not require keeping the connection open but does require your device polling data from the server. This is actually true for any protocol but the cost of keeping connection open varies by protocol. If your application is wired then just keep the connection open, it does not use much energy. If it is wireless then WiFi and 3G are both power hungry. Take a look at bluetooth or zigbee.

Comment: @Augusto: For absolute minimum power requirement consider abandoning standards altogether. Nordic and Texas Instrument both make excellent low power radio chipsets.